# Как мне сконвертировать IP?

Tags: php

Имеется IP - 95.153.128.120  и данный IP как то конвертируется, на выходе получается - 1603895416

С помощью какой функции и или еще чего конвертируется данный IP?

Comment: ((256*95+153)*256+128)*256+120 = 1603895416.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в php есть функция

```
int ip2long ( string $ip_address )
```

> ip2long — Конвертирует строку, содержащую (IPv4) Интернет-адрес с точками в целое число (long)

Пример

```
$long = ip2long($ip);
```

Возвращает целое число или FALSE, если параметр ip_address содержит ошибку.

[документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ip2long.php)

---

и обратное функция

```
string long2ip ( string $proper_address )
```

> long2ip — Конвертирует адрес в формате "длинное целое"(long integer) в, содержащую адрес Интернет сети(IPv4), стандартную строку с точками

Возвращает Интернет IP адрес в виде строки.

[документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.long2ip.php)